# How to animate a bezier curve over a given duration

Tags: unity

I have created a bezier curve by adding the following script to an empty game object in the inspector. This draws to complete curve at once when I run the code. How can I animate it over a given period of time, say 2 or 3 seconds?

```
public class BCurve : MonoBehaviour {

LineRenderer lineRenderer;
public Vector3 point0, point1, point2;
int numPoints = 50;
Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[50];

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Sprites/Default"));
    lineRenderer.startColor = lineRenderer.endColor = Color.white;
    lineRenderer.startWidth = lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.1f;
    lineRenderer.positionCount = numPoints;

    DrawQuadraticCurve ();

}

void DrawQuadraticCurve ()  {
    for (int i = 1; i < numPoints + 1; i++) {
        float t = i / (float)numPoints;
        positions [i - 1] = CalculateLinearBeziearPoint (t, point0, point1, point2);

     }
    lineRenderer.SetPositions(positions);
}

 Vector3 CalculateLinearBeziearPoint (float t, Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1,    Vector3 p2)   {

    float u = 1 - t;
    float tt = t * t;
    float uu = u * u;
    Vector3 p = uu * p0 + 2 * u * t * p1 + tt * p2;

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing all the work at once. You could do this in `Update()` and just render the points one by one, or you could reveal it slowly, by setting it to an image and [then revealing](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image-fillAmount.html) it over a [linear interpolation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html).

There's also one more method, you could just *not* draw the bezier curve from your calculations, but instead make a gameobject (preferably invisible) follow it. Attaching a [trail renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html) to the gameobject will give you a nice drawing effect, which you can [adjust all sorts of ways](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137955/how-to-make-a-2d-neon-like-trail-effect-in-unity/137956#137956).