# How to create inline glow shader for 2d polygon in CG using Unity Shader Lab?

Tags: unity, shaders, cg, shaderlab

So here is what I am trying to do. Given irregular polygon (on the left) I would like to be able to create a shader that would resemble Photoshop inline glow effect with opaque fill (on the right).

[image]

Creating similar effect for 3d object I can achieve with Fresnel function. However, I am not able to do it for a flat surface of any given irregular 2d polygon.

EDIT

I am planning on using Voronoi method to generate polygons and then connecting individual polygons to territory shapes based on which player owns them. Which, then will have border material applied. What I need is effectively border (or territory) shader. That means shader has to work for more irregular shapes, like the one below.

[image]

Comment: This will require either: 1) rendering your polygon to an intermediate buffer to blur, then using the fuzzy edges from that buffer as a glow weight in a subsequent pass, or 2) encoding an edge proximity or pseudo-normal into the vertices and using the interpolated result in the fragment shader. Is one route or the other more practical for your use case?

Comment: Can you maybe modify [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/137956/93538) to suit your needs?

Comment: @DMGregory I guess either method would do. Which one is easier? Would you mind elaborating bit more on either (both) of them.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I think it looks promising. I will try to dig into it and share my finding in few days. Would you be able to assist with that a bit? I am really open to and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: To be honest, both routes are kind of annoying in different ways. ;) Can you tell us more about how these shapes are used in your game, or how they're generated? That context might lend itself better to one approach or the other. Of course, you could also just bake this glow in with Photoshop in advance if the sprites are available at edit time — much easier than doing it dynamically. ;)

Comment: That is the problem. Shapes are generated inside of the game. Thought of Photoshop but it wouldn't work. I will be using [Voronoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) method to generate polygons and then connecting individual polygons to territory shapes. Which, then will have border material applied. What I need is effectively border (or territory) shader.